# Removing duplicate names in array using Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js

I'm trying to figure out how to remove duplicate names for a Google Maps project using Knockout JS. I have a list of coffee shops (multiple locations for a few chains) and I only want the name to show once. Here is my JS:

```
function AppViewModel() {
  this.header = ko.observable("Wilmington Coffee Shops");

  // List of coffee shops to select
  var self = this; 
  self.shops = ko.observableArray([
    {title: 'Port City Java', location: {lat: 34.235912, lng: -77.948826}},
    {title: 'Port City Java', location: {lat: 34.238930, lng: -77.949028}},
    {title: 'Port City Java', location: {lat: 34.237872, lng: -77.921174}},
    {title: 'Port City Java', location: {lat: 34.201974, lng: -77.922590}},
    {title: 'Port City Java', location: {lat: 34.242096, lng: -77.863673}},
    {title: 'Port City Java', location: {lat: 34.194293, lng: -77.910822}},
    {title: 'Starbucks', location: {lat: 34.216803, lng: -77.906956}},
    {title: 'Starbucks', location: {lat: 34.242066, lng: -77.828570}},
    {title: 'Starbucks', location: {lat: 34.196443, lng: -77.890236}},
    {title: 'Folks on Fourth', location: {lat: 34.243700, lng: -77.945501}},
    {title: '24 South Coffee House', location: {lat: 34.234496, lng: -77.948725}},
    {title: 'Karen\'s Cafe', location: {lat: 34.238730, lng: -77.948981}},
    {title: 'Luna Caffè', location: {lat: 34.228263, lng: -77.940812}},
    {title: 'Folks Cafe', location: {lat: 34.237704, lng: -77.934188}},
    {title: 'Zola Coffee & Tea', location: {lat: 34.213228, lng: -77.887951}},
    {title: 'Grinders Caffè', location: {lat: 34.212560, lng: -77.871677}},
    {title: 'Daily Grind', location: {lat: 34.241911, lng: -77.867955}},
    {title: 'Addicted to the Bean', location: {lat: 34.213678, lng: -77.886954}},
    {title: 'Bitty & Beau\'s Coffee', location: {lat: 34.242041, lng: -77.877485}},
    {title: 'Lucky Joe Craft Coffee', location: {lat: 34.266057, lng: -77.837758}},
    {title: 'Java Dog Coffee House', location: {lat: 34.239104, lng: -77.949228}},
    {title: 'Morning Glory Coffeehouse', location: {lat: 34.225831, lng: -77.929120}},
    {title: 'Bespoke Coffee & Dry Goods', location: {lat: 34.236453, lng: -77.947403}},
    {title: 'Brick + Mortar Coffee and Supply', location: {lat: 34.247251, lng: -77.946280}}
  ]);

  this.google = ko.observable(false);
  this.createMarkers = ko.computed(function(){
    if (self.google()){
      console.log("Google maps has finished loading");
      for (var i = 0; i < self.shops().length; i++) {
        var position = self.shops()[i].location;
        var title = self.shops()[i].title;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: position,
          title: title,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          map: map,
          id: i
        })
        self.shops()[i].marker = marker;
        markers.push(marker)
       }
       console.log(self.shops());
    }
  });
```

Here's how I appended it in my HTML:

```
<div>

            <ul data-bind="foreach: shops">
                <li>
                    <span data-bind="text: $data.title, click: $root.shopMarker"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the structure of the observableArray (for example show 'Port City Java' once then list the six locations as a nested array) or do you want to just show one title and location for each coffee shop?

Comment: I'm open to whatever the easiest/most reliable option is. I just want to make sure that each marker will have a proper infowindow attached (when I implement it) and every marker properly shows. I'm going to make the names clickable, so when you click "Starbucks", only the Starbucks markers show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're OK to change the structure of shops array, then you can change it and group them based on the title from the beginning.

It will look more or less like this.

```
 [
   {
    title: 'Port City Java', 
    locations: [
      { position: { lat: 34.235912, lng: -77.948826 } },
      { position: { lat: 34.238930, lng: -77.949028 } }
      // other locations
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Starbucks', 
    locations: [
      { position: { lat: 34.216803, lng: -77.906956 } },
      { position: { lat: 34.242066, lng: -77.828570 } },
      // other locations
    ]
  }
  // other shops
]
```

I also noticed `createMarkers` of AppViewModel which is a computed property doesn't return anything. You just want to add property `marker` to the shop if the loading is finished. So instead of using computed, you can use [`.subscribe`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) and do the following:

```
function AppViewModel() {
  this.header = ko.observable("Wilmington Coffee Shops");

  // List of coffee shops to select
  var self = this; 
  self.shops = ko.observableArray([
    {
      title: 'Port City Java', 
      locations: [
        { position: { lat: 34.235912, lng: -77.948826 } },
        { position: { lat: 34.238930, lng: -77.949028 } }
        // other locations
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'Starbucks', 
      locations: [
        { position: { lat: 34.216803, lng: -77.906956 } },
        { position: { lat: 34.242066, lng: -77.828570 } },
        // other locations
      ]
    }
    // other shops
  ]);
  this.google = ko.observable(false);
  this.google.subscribe(function(isLoadingFinished) {
    if (isLoadingFinished){
      console.log("Google maps has finished loading");
      for (var i = 0; i < self.shops().length; i++) {
        var shop = self.shops()[i];
        shop.locations.forEach(function(location){
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location.position,
            title: shop.title,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map,
            id: i
          })
          // add a new property called marker to the location object
          location.marker = marker;
        });
      }
      console.log(self.shops());
    } 
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @jbrally happy to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

are you allowed to use underscore? if so

```
  this.distinctShops = ko.computed(function() {
   var uniques = _.map(_.groupBy(ko.toJS(self.shops),function(doc){
           return doc.title;
      }),function(grouped){
           return grouped[0];
       });
     return uniques;
  }, this);
}
```

here is a working fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/du6dbdu6/

Comment: Did you include underscorejs?

Comment: There's a way to write it KO, I just can't figure it

Comment: sure, search around sure there are a million different way to get distinct values in javascript.  as for knockout utilities here is a nice page that shows some good ones.  http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html